# pyramid from localhost to live

Tags: python, mod-wsgi, pyramid

Hi guys I am having some trouble here and so i'm asking for some advise.

I built a pyramid app, it works perfectly on localhost, now I'm uploading it to a vps and i'm running into all kinds of trouble. My site is hosted on mercurial.

please don't reference this: http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/tutorials/modwsgi/index.html

I've tried that many times and Googled a lot, that's why I'm asking the question here.

I'm on python 2.7

1. I create a virtualenv
2. activate the virtualenv
3. pip -r requirements to download all the requirements
4. then python setup.py install

I now have a folder structure like this:

```
appname_dir/
     appname_module/
        static/
        template/
        __init__.py
        views.py
```

keep in mind I didn't name my folders appname_dir and appname_module.

I create my app.wsgi file inside my appname_module folder it looks like this

```
from pyramid.paster import get_app, setup_logging
ipath = '/path/to/appname_dir/production.ini'
application = get_app(ipath, 'main')
```

I've tried creating a virtual host file similar to the one below

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin contact@domain.com
        ServerName domain.com
        ServerAlias www.domain.com

        UseCanonicalName On

        WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/my/app.wsgi
        <Directory /path/to/folder/that/contains/app.wsgi>
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        Alias /static /path/to/app/static/folder
        <Directory /path/to/app/static/folder>
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog /path/to/app/folder/logs/error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog /path/to/app/folder/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

that doesn't work

I've tried to add custom apache conf file similar to the one below

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
WSGIPassAuthorization On
WSGIDaemonProcess pyramid user=username group=groupname threads=6 \
   python-path=/path/to/virtualenv/site-packages
WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/app.wsgi

<Directory /path/to/appname_dir>
  WSGIProcessGroup pyramid
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

and still no go. Typically their a 500 error with this code in the apache error log files

```
Target WSGI script cannot be loaded as Python module
```

can anyone help explain what's going on or how I can fix this. Please pointing me to other SO answers isn't helpful I've spent all day trying to figure this out.

Comment: You ask for no references to the documentation page you linked but I've noticed a problem between your version and theirs, any suggestions?

Comment: I was referring to people just saying, go read .... , i've spent all day today reading mod_wsgi docs and I'm still at 0 as far as getting thing thing up and running. Do you have any advise to help solve this problem?

Comment: in your `application = get_app(ipath, 'main')` line-- the ipath you use is a directory whereas in the documentation, it's a link to a .ini configuration file.  Read point 7 of the doc.

Comment: that's a typo the ipath = '/path/to/production.ini'  i'll fix that in the above question.

Comment: You don't mention adjusting the permissions to allow Apache to read the wsgi file-- did you do that? Also the 'Target...' error-- is there more information before and after that in the log file?

Comment: has anyone here successfully deployed a pyramid app with wsgi as described in the documentation I linked earlier? what setup do you guys to deploy a pyramid app?

Comment: When users activate the virtualenv or use pip instead of easy_install to install stuff, things go sideways. As long as you follow the official docs linked above, it should work. In step 6, note that you should install your app in `~/modwsgi/env/myapp`.

Comment: installing your app in ~/modwsgi you then have to make your whole root directory readable to everyone which the creator of this wsgi thing says not to do, here's [the talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yoR9WhM3EiA) it seems this mod_wsgi stuff is bunk it's like your saying follow the directions as if I'd be here asking on a public forum without first attempting it. So far no one has offered up anything other than referring back to the original article which I've tried many times.

Answer (score 0):

Well I was able to solve the problem by moving away from apache and mod_wsgi, I setup nginx and uwsgi. If I need apache I can proxy connections from nginx to apache but I don't see me needing to take that route anytime soon.